# What would be a word for this scenario?

Tags: word-choice

What would be a good word/term for someone who refuses something despite not having their own option. Just rejection with no solution. I hope I made it clear enough.

Comment: This would be clearer if you included an example of what you mean.

Comment: I assume you are looking for something negative, but there’s nothing inherently wrong with knowing that something is not the answer even if they don’t know what the answer is.

Comment: I don't think there's a specific term for this.